# Android Keystore - invalid key exception - preferred provider doesn't support key (ONLY ON EMULATOR)

Tags: java, android, security, keystore, provider

I have posted this question on the conscrypt github page ([here](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/issues/497)) but before I give up on this I thought I would post here.

**Background summary**

My app downloads a file from our server that has 2-way authentication enabled. I generate a keypair using the following code. My code works correctly when I test on my actual tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 on api 24). However, I cannot get this to work on any emulator so far (api 24, 25 and 26). The app crashes with the exception below (full log listed at the bottom)

```
...android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:666)
    W/System.err:   ... 41 more
    W/System.err: Could not find provider for algorithm: NONEwithRSA
```

**My key pair generation code:**

```
try {
      KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        alias,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY )
        .setKeySize(keySize)
        .setSignaturePaddings(SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
        .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
        .build();
      KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
      keyGen.initialize(spec);
      return keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
      return null;
    }
```

The error from the crash log says it could not find a provider for the algorithm "NONEwithRSA". However I ran the following code on both the emulator and the tablet and here are the results:

```
for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders())
        for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices())
          if (service.getType().equals("Signature") && service.getAlgorithm().equals("NONEwithRSA"))
            algorithms.add(service.getAlgorithm());...
```

Results of the providers that contain Signature.NONEwithRSA for both the emulator and tablet:

**provider** = OpenSSLProvider

**service** = AndroidOpenSSL: Signature.NONEwithRSA -> com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSignatureRawRSA attributes: {SupportedKeyClasses=com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey|java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey|com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPublicKey|java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey}

**provider** = AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaroundProvider

**service** = AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround: Signature.NONEwithRSA -> android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreRSASignatureSpi$NONEWithPKCS1Padding attributes: {SupportedKeyClasses=android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStorePrivateKey|android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStorePublicKey}

According to this, there is a provider that exists **OpenSSLProvide**r that contains the **NONEwithRSA** signature algorithm...so I don't understand why it would crash with `Could not find provider for algorithm: NONEwithRSA...`and why only on the emulator.

I got a response from someone on the Conscrypt page saying the following:

> It looks like this is a problem because Android Keystore is throwing
>   an exception when trying to use the key for some reason, probably
>   related to the fact the actual device has secure hardware-backed key
>   storage and the emulator doesn't emulate that sufficiently accurately
>   for Keystore's needs.
>
> Unfortunately, Android N is long since shipped, so there's not much we
>   can do to change the platform's behavior here. Your best bet is to use
>   ProviderInstaller from Google Play Services to get a modern version of
>   Conscrypt into your app, which should hopefully make this problem go
>   away. See
>   https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller

Prior to me asking them I had not tested on an emulator with Oreo (api 26), so I tested that and still saw the same issue. I also tested what he recommended and was not able to get that to fix the issue. I replied back, but have not gotten a response.

Is there something I am doing wrong or is this just an issue with the emulator bc it doesn't properly emulate the keystore? Any other ideas for work arounds?

**Crash log:**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x8c026640: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:04000044:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:internal error (external/conscrypt/src/main/native/org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp:1958 0x995ce266:0x00000000)

SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x8af34480: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:04000044:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:internal error (external/conscrypt/src/main/native/org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp:1958 0x995ce266:0x00000000)

W/System.err: Preferred provider doesn't support key:
W/System.err: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
W/System.err:     at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:727)
W/System.err:     at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:748)
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:219)
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.engineInitSign(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.engineInitSign(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:77)
W/System.err:     at java.security.Signature$Delegate.init(Signature.java:1208)
W/System.err:     at java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Signature.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1232)
W/System.err:     at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:607)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.CryptoUpcalls.rawSignDigestWithPrivateKey(CryptoUpcalls.java:86)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:281)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)
W/System.err:     at com.saic.refmanone.models.RetrofitFileDownloadService.downloadFile(RetrofitFileDownloadService.java:239)
W/System.err:     at com.saic.refmanone.models.WebBundlerUpdateService.getUpdatesForBook(WebBundlerUpdateService.java:56)
W/System.err:     at com.saic.refmanone.models.FetchBookUpdatesUtility.fetchAllBookUpdates(FetchBookUpdatesUtility.java:36)
W/System.err:     at com.saic.refmanone.models.FetchBookUpdatesIntentService.onHandleIntent(FetchBookUpdatesIntentService.java:91)
W/System.err:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Incompatible digest
W/System.err:     at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:666)
W/System.err:   ... 41 more
W/System.err: Could not find provider for algorithm: NONEwithRSA
```

Comment: Whoever you are, I owe you big time. This bug has been the bane of my existence for a few weeks now. I had no idea it was based on the fact I was using an emulator + android keystore.